# How to emulate mass storage device in Genymotion Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, usb, emulation, genymotion

I currently have a cable that allows me to plug in a flash drive into my phone (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075352/get-access-to-usb-mass-storage-device-in-android/24099213#24099213)). My phone then picks up the flash drive as a "mass storage device" that has been attached.

I started using the [Genymotion Emulator](http://www.genymotion.com) and was wondering if it's possible to emulate a mass storage device being attached to the emulator? Thanks in advance.