# How to access Micro USB External SD Card Reader in android

Tags: android, android-sdcard, sd-card, usb-otg

I have an external sd card reader, I can plug it into the micro usb connector and access data from sd card with a file explorer.

I pluged the card reader on Nexus5 (6.0.1) and Asus tablet (4.1.2)
The sd card is mount on

> /mnt/media_rw/THE_SERIAL_NUMBER_OF_SD_CARD

Or in:

> /removables/NAME_OF_SD_CARD_PARTITION

I didn't find any `Android SDK` call to get the path to the mounted sd card, they are all made for internal sd card reader.

Is there any way to be able to access data from sd card, regardless the ROM and where the sd card is mount? It would be really awesome.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I think this is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075352/get-access-to-usb-mass-storage-device-in-android

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that. But in the answer they use static path to a specific usb device... Is there, at least, a limited path number to ckeck, for mounted usb devices?

I'm looking into [USB Host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) but it's look tricky to transfer files.

Comment: You could just get the directory content for `/mnt/media_rw`, `/removables/` and `/storage/` and then decide which you want to use or similar.