# Android Things filesystem

Tags: android, file-io, usb-drive, android-external-storage, android-things

I am building this app on android things. I want to be able to give it access to media files on a USB stick or maybe even the raspberry pi's SDcard. I don't know what I'll have it do with those files yet but I just wanna know if its possible. If it isn't that's fine I have other solutions but I figured I would start with the obvious approach first.

Comment: Also interested in why you want to do this? (to give you alternative answers)

Comment: I fell in love with the idea of embedded android lol The app I am building is acting like a hub for all my smart devices and I added cast to it recently. I thought it might be cool if I could get it to cast media from external storage to my tv. I basically want to see how far I can push this platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm didn't try it, but seems it's possible by the same way as in normal Android OS. To do this You should mount Your USB dongle into the filesystem somewhere e.g. in new folder `/mnt/usb` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42474815/6950238) answer of [Onik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3290339/onik) or [that](https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/remote-storage-android-things#mount-usb-drive) project of [Keval Patel](https://github.com/kevalpatel2106):

> **Mount USB drive:**
>
> Plug you USB drive at any of the USB port in your Raspberry Pi.
>
> Open adb shell by typing below command in terminal (Make sure your raspberry pi is connected via adb):
>
> `adb shell`
>
> Mount the USB drive by running below command in adb shell (Your USB drive should be formatted in FAT file system):
>
> `su mkdir /mnt/usb`
>
> `mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/block/sda1 /mnt/usb`

where

`sda1` is the first partition of the first disk (`sdb1` is the first partition of the second disk, etc.) and `/mnt/usb` - new folder for mounted USB dongle.

Then You can access to mounted USB dongle something like this way:

```
File usbDongleRoot = new File("/mnt/usb");
```

(or something like this).

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28652419/6950238) answer of [JBA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1720332/jba) and that [repo](https://github.com/shakalaca/USB-OTG-Manager) of [Shaka Huang](https://github.com/shakalaca).