# Android Things- Pico i.MX7 USB port data accessing directly From flash drive

Tags: android-things

My doubt about Android The **Pico Pro kit (Pico i.MX7 Dual development board)**.For my project in want **access the external data files**,so i preference to use the USB port on the board. It is possible to copy or move file from flash drive to internal memory using USB port .**But I need directly need to access the files from flash drive(Pen drive)** .
Is it possible!

If any one know help me....

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45537879/6950238) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Things filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537879/android-things-filesystem)

Comment: Shell into the device, [mount the USB drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465326/how-to-mount-a-usb-drive-on-an-android-things-app/42474815#42474815) and copy files from the USB drive into internal storage with either `cp` or `mv` commands.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Sir, i tried those shell codes i got,this...      $ adb shell

su mkdir /mnt/usb
su: invalid uid/gid 'mkdir'
mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/block/sda1 /mnt/usb
mount: bad /etc/fstab: No such file or directory